# How can I save a return value from a method and then passing it to another method?

Tags: java

Im confused as to how to save the integers generated from the 'makeThrow()' and 'makeThrow(int throwType)' constructors and then passing them to the 'lastThrow()' method.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RochambeauPlayer
extends java.lang.Object
    {
      private String name;
      private int wins;
      private int throwType;

      public java.lang.String lastThrow(){
        if(throwType == 0){
          String rock = "ROCK";
          return rock;
        }
        else if(throwType == 1){
          String paper = "PAPER";
          return paper;
        }
        else{
          String scissors = "SCISSORS";
          return scissors;
        }
      }
```

Throw numbers are either randomly generated or inputted by the user and saved to throwType

```
      public int makeThrow(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int throwType = rand.nextInt(3);
        this.throwType = throwType;
        return throwType;
      }

      public int makeThrow(int throwType){
        this.throwType = throwType;
        return throwType;
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are methods not constructors.

You can't pass anything to the `lastThrow` method because it doesn't take any parameters.

Both your `makeThrow()` methods are already changing the value of `throwType` so the next time you call `lastThrow()` it will return the correct `String`.